# Extract the price from a string yields ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.95.00'

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a price value as float in python. The price comes as `Rs.95.00`

```
one = float(''.join(c for c in price_laughs if (c.isdigit() or c =='.')))
print(one)
```

I tried to extract the price using the following code, but since there's a '.' at the beginning, i'm unable to get the value as 95.00. How can i extract the price as a float value.

Comment: Will it always be `Rs.` and then the value?

Comment: Please think carefully about the program requirements. When "the price comes as `Rs.95.00`", **what is the rule that tells you** that the `95.00` part is the number?

Comment: yes the price always comes as Rs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the value is always going to contain `Rs.`, one way is to split one time from left passing `maxsplit=1` then to get the last value.

```py
>>> v='Rs.95.00'
>>> float(v.split('.', 1)[-1])
95.0
```

Answer (score -1):

If price is always prefixed by `Rs.` then simply substring it and you are done:

```py
price = 'Rs.95.00'
val = float(price[3:])
print(val)
```